# Returning custom validation error in Laravel user validation/creation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In user creation proccess I need to query a external server for additional data and if that happens to fail i need to return an error at validation or creation. How is it best to do this? Here is the default Laravel code for registering user with some of my attemps:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $query = queryExternalServerForAdditionalData();

    if($query->success){
      //add data from query to other user data?
      //$data['data'] = $query->data;

      return Validator::make($data, [
          'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
          'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
          'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
      ]);
    } else {
      //somehow return an error, but how?
    }
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    // or maybe do the query and error return here?
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        // add my additional data
        // 'data' => $data['data']
    ]);
}
```

So as you can see my question is that how can i return an error from validator or create method? I tried to return redirect() with an error property added, but i got an error that something else was expected by the method calling validator/create and redirect was returned so that doesn't seem to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best way to do this is [creating form requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation).

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users|check_server_for_additional_data',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ];
}
```

As an example, I added `check_server_for_additional_data`, a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules) for email field (An error message will appear in the email field).

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('check_server_for_additional_data', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return // queryExternalServerForAdditionalData()
        });
    }
}
```

Don't forget to defining the error message (`resources/lang/LOCALE/validation.php`)

```
"check_server_for_additional_data" => "Umm ohh.. Invalid!",
```